# ProTools plugins which have MIDI 'learn' functionality

Tags: pro-tools, ipad, midi, automation

I'm using touchOSC and Osculator on my iPad.

Which plugins do you know of (RTAS or AAX) that have OSC or MIDI control functionality inbuilt by the manufacturer? I'm not talking so much about Instruments, more FX --- EQ \ Reverbs \ Delays \ Etc.

The ones I know about so far

-Fab Filter plugins (which are pretty cool)
https://www.fabfilter.com/

-Blue Cat Audio
https://www.bluecataudio.com/Products/Bundle_AllPluginsPack/

-Massive
https://www.native-instruments.com/en/products/komplete/synths-samplers/massive/

-Izotope IRIS

-NI Reaktor

Suggestions?

Comment: REAKTOR has thousands of FX,EQ,Verb,Delay type ensembles and allows for midi & OSC learn.  You can also design your own custom ensembles with it.



Comment: thanks @Brad --- does it play nice with ProTools in rewire, do you know?

Comment: Reaktor as an AAX .. could be an excellent option! Going to give the demo a fry. Thanks